# Qt: Triggering code when QMainWindow is maximized/unmaximized

Tags: c++, qt

I need some C++ code to trigger **ONLY** if/when the user maximizes or de-maximizes (floats) a QMainWindow. The program will still run without this extra code if need be but having this feature would definitely help aesthetics. Basically, a main splitter in the GUI should be at 25% if the window is maximized and 50% if it is un-maximized. (default floating window state)

Right now, the user has to drag it manually if they want more room and most of the screen real estate on one side of the splitter is wasted since QSplitter wants to default to 50% regardless of window size. It's annoying but it's not going to ruin your day if it happens.

I checked to see if QMainWindow has a slot for checking the maximized state of a window but there's none as far as I know. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

To query the current window state:

- http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qwidget.html#windowState

To listen for state changes, override:

- http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qwidget.html#changeEvent

If you have a QEvent::WindowStateChange, call your splitter placement code.  For all cases, pass along the event to the base class event handler.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of a way to do this but you may want to consider that switching from "maximized" to "restore down" (or vice versa) is no guarantee of a significant change in window size if the user had already stretched the window quite large before maximizing it. If you do find a way to receive these events, you would probably still want to check the actual window size before making your adjustments.

You may just want to handle resize events for making your adjustments which would allow you to handle cases where the user manually stretches or shrinks the window (as well as when they maximize or restore). I'm not sure I would find that behavior satisfactory as a user however so maybe offer it as a configurable item :)